# vb.net insert into database from checked list box

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I have a checked list box with 6 items . i use the designer to set the binding source to the coulm in my data base named "Gad" the problem is when i select 2 or 3 items from checked list the coulm "gad" on my database get the first selected only .. i want the all  selected items saved in this this coulm separated by dashes like item1 - item2 - item 3

Comment: What's the point of providing an empty SelectedIndexChanged handler?

Comment: Not clear at all. Say what you want to achieve, because it sounds like you've gone well wrong.

Comment: i set the checkedlistbox to insert into access data base field named watches .. the problem is the field get only one cheked item .. example : when i select red watch & blue watch from checkedlistbox and click save the database field get only red watch ....sorry for my bad language

Comment: Have you read the books online about checkedlistbox? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bob As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each item As String In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        bob.Append(item)
        bob.Append(" - ")
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(bob.ToString)
End Sub
```